# Clear find result in notepad++ with keystrokes or plugin

Tags: windows-7, notepad++, macros

I'm trying to find a keystroke or plugin (that I could assign a hotkey to) to do the following:

- Focus the "Find Result" window (I know the F7 key does the focusing,
  but I think it's also a toggle)
- Select all of the text within same
  window
- Choose (and thus execute) the action "Clear All"

I checked in the Plugin Manager and can't seem to find one that looks like it's meant to do what I need.

I recorded a macro to do this, but the macro does not repeat the steps as they were when I recorded the macro.  Also, I'm currently unable to save them.  I've mentioned it in the Notepad++ forums (inability to save macro) and there is a bug already reported.

Does anyone have any ideas to try here? Or can point me in the right direction of creating a plugin by which to do what I need. Will I need to learn Scintilla commands in order to accomplish this?

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: If it's a known bug then you'll probably have to wait for it to be fixed.

Comment: Hi @Karan yes, the saving the macro part seems to be a bug to wait for a fix. I'm wondering if anyone in the community has come across the need to clear out the Find Results window and could share a pointer or 2.

Comment: Can you tell us what you're trying to automate? Just this (which seems trivial to do with a mouse) or is it part of a larger macro that performs other actions as well?

Comment: I'm trying to automate the steps in the bulleted list above. Yes, it is trivial to do with mouse, but in my current project I'm doing these clicks over and over again. It's a preference thing.

Comment: Ok. I might be wrong but as far as I can see these extra panes that open up are not under the purview of macros.

Comment: @Karan Interesting point. Ok, thanks for helping/assisting with info.

Comment: I have the same question is 2021, any solutions so far?

Comment: Sorry, no solution as such. Or none that I know of. I will close this page/question out if possible. I totally forgot about it after all this time.